# How to use regex to input dates from the user?

Tags: regex, date

This is part of a larger program - I kept the code as much as possible unchanged for detection of bugs. Here I have series of JTextFields where user inputs "past" dates in European format (dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm etc.). A button below tries to save the dates in a database (not implemented here) - but before that it checks whether the format is correct. Any wrong format or "future" date should generate error and make the text color red. For the ease of user, if one inputs part of a date/time the program tries to predict what the complete date should be considering the present time and and the fact that it is a past date. Now everything works fine except one thing. If the user enters only "time" (HH:mm) all digits except the last one from the HH part is truncated and is considered as day(dd). Could you please tell me where lies the bug and how to get it correct? (I copied the regex from another post and modified it - so I do not have the complete understanding of it). Here is the program and output (the program was run on 14.8.2020 8:00am):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.DateTimeException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class InputDateTest implements ActionListener {

    static int max = 15;
    static JFrame f = new JFrame();
    static GridBagLayout gb = new GridBagLayout();
    static GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    static int presentLineNumber = 0;
    static JTextField invDate[] = new JTextField[max];
    static JButton b;
    static LocalDateTime dates[] = new LocalDateTime[max];
    int ready = 1, error = 0, atLeastOne = 0;
    
    private static final Pattern date_pattern = Pattern
            .compile("^\\s*((?:(?:\\d+(?:[./]\\s*)?){0,3})?)\\s*((?:(?:\\d+[:/.]?)+)?)");
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputDateTest idt = new InputDateTest();
        f.setLayout(gb);
        for(int i=0; i<max; i++) {
            invDate[presentLineNumber] = new JTextField();
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START; 
            c.gridx = 0;      
            c.gridy = presentLineNumber;
            c.weightx = 0.1;
            c.weighty = 0.0;
            c.gridwidth = 1;
            c.gridheight = 1;
            gb.setConstraints(invDate[presentLineNumber], c);
            f.add(invDate[presentLineNumber]);
            presentLineNumber++;
        }
        b = new JButton("Save");
        b.addActionListener(idt);
        c.gridy = presentLineNumber+1;
        gb.setConstraints(b, c);
        f.add(b);
        
        f.setLocation(400, 100);
        f.setSize(200, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.revalidate();
        f.repaint();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        for(int i =0; i<presentLineNumber; i++) {
            String str = invDate[i].getText();
            invDate[i].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ); 
            dates[i] = now;
            if(str!=null&&!str.isEmpty()) {
                Matcher matcher = date_pattern.matcher(str);
                if (matcher.matches()) {
                    try {
                        int yearAdjusted = 0, monthAdjusted = 0, dayAdjusted = 0;
                        String dateGroup = matcher.group(1).trim();
                        if (!"".equals(dateGroup)) {
                            String[] items = dateGroup.split("\\D+");
                            int len = items.length;
                            int y=now.getYear(), m=now.getMonthValue(), d=now.getDayOfMonth();
                            if(len>2) y = Integer.valueOf(items[2]);
                            if(len>1) m = Integer.valueOf(items[1]);
                            d = Integer.valueOf(items[0]);
                            int year = now.getYear();
                            if (y<100) y = y + year - (year%100);
                            if(len>2) {
                                if(now.getYear()>=y) {
                                    dates[i] = dates[i].withYear(y);
                                    yearAdjusted = 1;   
                                }else {
                                    error =1;
                                    invDate[i].setForeground(Color.RED);
                                }
                            }
                            if(len>1) {
                                if(now.getMonthValue()>=m||now.getYear()>y) {
                                    dates[i] = dates[i].withMonth(m);
                                    monthAdjusted = 1;
                                }else if(yearAdjusted == 0){
                                    dates[i] = dates[i].minusYears(1);
                                    dates[i] = dates[i].withMonth(m);
                                    y=y-1;
                                    monthAdjusted = 1;
                                }else {
                                    error =1;
                                    invDate[i].setForeground(Color.RED);
                                }
                            }
                            if(len>0) {
                                if(now.getDayOfMonth()>=d||now.getMonthValue()>m||now.getYear()>y){
                                    dates[i] = dates[i].withDayOfMonth(d);
                                    dayAdjusted = 1;
                                }else if(monthAdjusted == 0) {
                                    dates[i] = dates[i].minusMonths(1);
                                    dates[i] = dates[i].withDayOfMonth(d);
                                    dayAdjusted = 1;
                                }else if(yearAdjusted == 0){
                                    dates[i] = dates[i].minusYears(1);
                                    dates[i] = dates[i].withDayOfMonth(d);
                                    dayAdjusted = 1;
                                }else {
                                    error =1;
                                    invDate[i].setForeground(Color.RED);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        String timeGroup = matcher.group(2).trim();
                        if (!"".equals(timeGroup)) {
                            String[] items = timeGroup.split("\\D+");
                            int len = items.length;
                            if(len>0) dates[i] = dates[i].withHour(Integer.valueOf(items[0]));
                            if(len>1) dates[i] = dates[i].withMinute(Integer.valueOf(items[1]));
                            if(dates[i].isAfter(now)) {
                                if(dayAdjusted == 0) {
                                    dates[i] = dates[i].minusHours(24);
                                }else {
                                    error =1;
                                    invDate[i].setForeground(Color.RED);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("date = "+ dates[i].format(dtf));
                    } catch (DateTimeException d) {
                        error = 1;
                        invDate[i].setForeground(Color.RED);
                    }
                }else {
                    error = 1;
                    invDate[i].setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }
        if(atLeastOne == 0||error == 1) ready = 0;
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

```
11/2/18 3:45    ->date = 11.02.2018 03:45       (ok)
12/7/2020 21:21 ->date = 12.07.2020 21:21       (ok)
9:48            ->date = 13.08.2020 09:48       (ok)
14:32           ->date = 01.08.2020 04:32       (expected date = 13.08.2020 14:32)
125:57          ->date = 12.08.2020 05:57       (expected error)
```

Comment: Regex is the wrong approach. You might use it for basic format checking, and you can even write one that only matches real dates, but you need code behind the input field to calculate if the date is a past date. Regex only matches patterns, it has no “logic” capability

Comment: Thank you. I used regex only for pattern matching - and this is where the bug lies. Yes, detecting past date is another issue, there is no problem with that part.

Comment: Regex can certainly be used to match past dates, just as it can be used to match valid dates (such as 29.02 is valid only in a leap year). Whether regex is the most appropriate solution is another matter.

Comment: I used regex only for date pattern matching, never tried to detect past date with regex. I agree my question was not perfect and a bit misguiding. Should I edit it?

Comment: As example
(?=.*((1([5-9])|2\d|3[0-1])-06-2020)|(((0-2]\d)|3[0-1])-(0[7-9]|1[0-2])-2020))
matches dates in 2020 later than 14.06.2020. Your program must handle such matches appropriately.
This match date is arbitrary and the year could be extended to cover 2021...

Comment: Though it was not my question, it is fantastic. (I believe there is one '[' missing before the 5th '0'). My question was the expression which I used is not working for HH:mm format. First H gets missed. Could you tell me why?

Comment: I only answered your question as to how regex can be used to match a past date.
You are correct about the missing [ - this is a typical typo that occurs when editing text rather than the original regex.

Comment: Tip: When you use regexes embedded in programs, I find it better to test the regex separately with some appropriate regex test tool and then convert the tested regex to the program environment, such as add required escape characters. Also for simplicity, use non-capturing groups only when warranted.

Comment: Thanks TonyR. I did as you suggested and found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following regex did the magic of matching a date pattern:

```
"^\\s*((?:(?:\\d+(?![\\d:])(?:[./]\\s*)?){0,3})?)\\s*((?:(?:\\d+[:/.]?)+)?)"
```